# Edit jquery tooltip script to disable default tooltips

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Here's a tooltip script from [webdesign tuts+](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/how-to-create-link-tooltips-using-css3-and-jquery/). Works great, but it fails to disable the default tooltip.

I lack the skills to update this script accordingly. I'd greatly appreciate an edit that will disable default tooltips!

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").mouseenter(function (e) { //event fired when mouse cursor enters "a" element
        var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "
        var $x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; //get mouse X coordinate relative to "a" element
        var $tooltip_text = $(this).attr("title"); //get title attribute of "a" element

        if ($tooltip_text.length > 0) { //display tooltip only if it has more than zero characters

            $(this).append('<div class="tooltip ' + $class_name + '">' + $tooltip_text + '</div>'); //append tooltip markup, insert class name and tooltip title from the values above

            $("a > div.tooltip.center").css("left", "" + $x - 103 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
            $("a > div.tooltip.left").css("left", "" + $x + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
            $("a > div.tooltip.right").css("left", "" + $x - 208 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left

            $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeIn(300); //display, animate and fade in the tooltip
        }
    });

    $("a").mouseleave(function () { //event fired when mouse cursor leaves "a" element
        var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "

        //fade out the tooltip, delay for 300ms and then remove the tooltip and end the custom queue
        $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeOut(300).delay(300).queue(function () {
            $(this).remove();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It removes the `title` attribute while the tooltip is showing, so the default one doesn't show, then it sets the `title` attribute again later.

Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pnc3r/2/

```
    var $tooltip_text;

    $("a").mouseenter(function (e) { //event fired when mouse cursor enters "a" element
            var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "
            var $x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; //get mouse X coordinate relative to "a" element
            $tooltip_text = $(this).attr("title"); //get title attribute of "a" element

            if ($(this).hasClass("tooltip_link")) {

                $(this).attr("title",""); // removes the tooltip
            }

            if ($tooltip_text.length > 0) { //display tooltip only if it has more than zero characters

                $(this).append('<div class="tooltip ' + $class_name + '">' + $tooltip_text + '</div>'); //append tooltip markup, insert class name and tooltip title from the values above

                $("a > div.tooltip.center").css("left", "" + $x - 103 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
                $("a > div.tooltip.left").css("left", "" + $x + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
                $("a > div.tooltip.right").css("left", "" + $x - 208 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left

                $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeIn(300); //display, animate and fade in the tooltip
            }
        });

        $("a").mouseleave(function () { //event fired when mouse cursor leaves "a" element

            $(this).attr("title",$tooltip_text); // puts the tooltip back
            $tooltip_text = "";

            var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "

            //fade out the tooltip, delay for 300ms and then remove the tooltip and end the custom queue
            $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeOut(300).delay(300).queue(function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        });
```

Comment: grc, this is simply awesome. Many thanks! Just one note, however. Your edit disables all default tooltips, not just the ones with a class of "tooltip." Any way to keep default tooltips active where I'm not using the new tooltips? Not sure if it means anything, but the actual class used in the html is "tooltip_link".

Comment: Ok i've updated the code and example so that it checks if the class is `tooltip_link` before removing the tooltip.

Comment: Oddly, default tooltips are still not working where the link is an image. Much improved, though, over the original. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this should work, though I haven't tested it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $tooltip_text;

$("a.tooltip_link").mouseenter(function (e) { //event fired when mouse cursor enters "a" element
        var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "
        var $x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; //get mouse X coordinate relative to "a" element
        $tooltip_text = $(this).attr("title"); //get title attribute of "a" element


    /* 
    *  My changes:
    */

        $(this).attr("title", ""); // remove title text to stop default tooltip

        // end changes (one more in the bottom function


    if ($tooltip_text.length > 0) { //display tooltip only if it has more than zero characters

        $(this).append('<div class="tooltip ' + $class_name + '">' + $tooltip_text + '</div>'); //append tooltip markup, insert class name and tooltip title from the values above

        $("a > div.tooltip.center").css("left", "" + $x - 103 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
        $("a > div.tooltip.left").css("left", "" + $x + "px"); //set tooltip position from left
        $("a > div.tooltip.right").css("left", "" + $x - 208 + "px"); //set tooltip position from left

        $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeIn(300); //display, animate and fade in the tooltip
    }
});

$("a.tooltip_link").mouseleave(function () { //event fired when mouse cursor leaves "a" element
    var $class_name = $(this).attr("class").slice(13); //get class attribute of "a" element after leaving 13 characters which is equal to "tooltip_link "

    //fade out the tooltip, delay for 300ms and then remove the tooltip and end the custom queue
    $("a > div.tooltip." + $class_name).fadeOut(300).delay(300).queue(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });


    /* 
    *  My changes:
    */
    $(this).attr("title", $tooltip_text); // return the title text to the anchor element
    // end changes


});
</script>
```

I commented around my changes so you can see them and maybe learn... that is assuming that what I've done actually works.

Comment: i fixed an error in my code, i had "this" instead of "$(this)"

Comment: Thanks, user797115. However, the default tooltips are now showing for all links, while the new tooltips are not displaying at all.

Comment: I apologize, it was late and I was too lazy to actually check my code. In any case, it looks like the above poster "Grc" has you taken care of. Sorry again!

Comment: @user705100 I know this has already been answered, but I tested and fixed my code. It now works, checking only tooltip_link classed links.

Comment: Nothing wrong with two good answers. Tested your updated script and it works. Thanks!